# Best practice to implement push notifications with Node.js

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, firebase, push-notification

I've got a task to implement push notifications on the backend side (Node.js + MongoDB) for the iOS and Android mobile apps. I wonder what is the best practice to perform this task.
Should I develop own custom notification server or use some of the platforms like Firebase or Parse Server?

Comment: Since Parse is now open source and developed using NodeJs, I could imagine that you could seek inspiration from them.